# RegExp: match known number

Tags: javascript, regex, floating-point

i want to match a known number(floating point or integer) with a string and finding number of that repeat.

like match 22 in "22.5 98 12 22 322"

how i can do it with regular expression ?

Comment: In the regex-based answers be aware that the `.` character has a special meaning. If you pass in a number, such as `22.53` you'll need to escape the period: `/22\.53/`

Comment: How would `22` match against `+22.00` or `0` against `-.0` and `+0` or `-.02` against `-0.0200` ?

Comment: @sln:before matching, numbers had converted to the correct(-.0 converted to 0 and +22.00 converted to 22) with parseFloat

Comment: @HosseiN - There is no concept of `numbers` in regular expressions. parseFloat parses and converts to a `number`. What you 'see' is rendered back to text. There is no corollation as `numbers` between that and other text in a string. You can either parse that rendered output from parseFloat (as text), build a regex that can parse a line of text for that equivalent, or , the equivalent, use `(?<=^|\s)(?=[^\s]*\d)([+-]?\d*[.]?\d*)(?=$|\s)` to find all number forms in the string then compare it as a number. There is no magic-pill that will grab 'numbers' in strings.. there are none!

Comment: @HosseiN - Btw, parseFloat renders `-.2` text to `-0.2` text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str.match(/substr/g).length
```

returns number of occurrences of "substr" in "str". For example:

```
str = "22.5 98 12 22 322"
num = str.match(/22/g).length
alert(num) // 3
```

If you want to match *integers* rather than just substrings, make sure the number is preceded and followed by a space:

```
str = "22.5 98 12 22 322"
num = str.match(/(^|\s)22($|\s)/g).length
alert(num) // 1
```

Another option, without regular expressions:

```
str = "22.5 98 12 22 322"
num = str.split(" ").filter(function(item) {
    return Number(item) === 22;
}).length;
```

Answer (score 4):

try using this:

```
if (numbers.indexOf("22") != -1) {
   //The number 22 is in the String
}
```

It's not exactly a regex but why use it when you don't need it?

Comment: i want to know number of repeat

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you should find only the numbers that repeat within the same string, you can use something like this:

```
var test_str = '22 34 55 45345 34 22 555';
var matches  = test_str.match(/(\b[0-9]+\b)(?=.+\b\1\b)/g); 
// matches contains ["22", "34"], but not "55"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "22.5 98 12 22 322";
var pattern = /22/g;
if (pattern.test(str)) {
    // it matches "22", do your logic here...
}
```

see [RegExp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) and [RegExp.test(string)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) for more

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good tool for you to explore regular expressions :)
http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Adopted from the site above:

```
function demoShowMatchClick() {
  var re = new RegExp("(?:^| )+(22(?:$| ))+");
  var m = re.exec("22.5 98 12 22 322");
  if (m == null) {
    alert("No match");
  } else {
    var s = "Match at position " + m.index + ":\n";
   for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
     s = s + m[i] + "\n";
   }
   alert(s);
 }
}
```

This will give you all matches and requires the number to be seperated by beginning or end of string or a whitespace.

Comment: You're right, the pattern doesn't require a space, terminator and so on, just matches one or more 22's.

Answer (score 0):

Corrolating integer/floating point numbers from text to regex is
very tricky, since regex has no such concept.

With dynamic input, all the work is constructing the regex programatically.
This example doesn't include scientific notation, but it could.

Pseudo code:

```
If the input matches this parse regex  
    /^  (?=.*\d)     // must be a digit in the input
        ([+-]?)      // capt (1), optional +/-
        [0]*         // suck up all leading 0's
        (\d*)        // capt (2), optional digits, will start with [1-9]
        ([.]?)       // capt (3), optional period
        (\d*?)       // capt (4), non-greedy optional digits, will start with [1-9]
        [0]*         // suck up all trailing 0's
     $/x

    sign = '[+]?';

    If !length $2 AND !length $4
         sign = '[+-]';
    Else
        If $1 == '-'
            sign = '[-]';
        Endif
    Endif

    whole = '[0]*';

    If  length $2
         whole = '[0]*' + $2;
    Endif

    decfrac = '[.]? [0]*';

    If  length $4
         $decfrac = '[.] ' + $4 + '[0]*';
    Endif

    regex = '/(?:^|\s)(?=\S*\d) ' +  "$sign $whole $decfrac" + ' (?:\s|$)/x';

Else
    //  input is not valid
Endif
```

This is a Perl test case.
The dynamic regex produced has not been tested,
I asume it works but I could be wrong.

```
@samps = (
'00000.0',
 '+.0',
 '-.0',
 '0.',
 '-0.00100',
 '1',
 '+.1',
 '+43.0910',
 '22',
 '33.e19',
);


for (@samps) 
{
   print "\nInput:  $_\n";

   if( /^ (?=.*\d) ([+-]?) [0]*(\d*) ([.]?) (\d*?)[0]*$/x )   # 1,2,3,4
   {

      my ($sign, $whole, $decfrac);

      $sign = '[+]?';

      if ( !length $2  && !length $4) {
           $sign = '[+-]';
      } elsif ($1 eq '-') {
           $sign = '[-]';
      }

      $whole = '[0]*';

      if ( length $2) {
          $whole = '[0]*'.$2;
      }

      $decfrac = '[.]? [0]*';

      if ( length $4) {
          $decfrac = '[.] '.$4.'[0]*';
      }


      my $regex = '/(?:^|\s)(?=\S*\d) '. "$sign $whole $decfrac" . ' (?:\s|$)/x';

      print "Regex:  $regex\n";
   }
   else {
      print "**input  '$_'  is not valid\n";
      next;
   }
}
```

Output

```
Input:  00000.0
Regex:  /(?:^|\s)(?=\S*\d) [+-] [0]* [.]? [0]* (?:\s|$)/x

Input:  +.0
Regex:  /(?:^|\s)(?=\S*\d) [+-] [0]* [.]? [0]* (?:\s|$)/x

Input:  -.0
Regex:  /(?:^|\s)(?=\S*\d) [+-] [0]* [.]? [0]* (?:\s|$)/x

Input:  0.
Regex:  /(?:^|\s)(?=\S*\d) [+-] [0]* [.]? [0]* (?:\s|$)/x

Input:  -0.00100
Regex:  /(?:^|\s)(?=\S*\d) [-] [0]* [.] 001[0]* (?:\s|$)/x

Input:  1
Regex:  /(?:^|\s)(?=\S*\d) [+]? [0]*1 [.]? [0]* (?:\s|$)/x

Input:  +.1
Regex:  /(?:^|\s)(?=\S*\d) [+]? [0]* [.] 1[0]* (?:\s|$)/x

Input:  +43.0910
Regex:  /(?:^|\s)(?=\S*\d) [+]? [0]*43 [.] 091[0]* (?:\s|$)/x

Input:  22
Regex:  /(?:^|\s)(?=\S*\d) [+]? [0]*22 [.]? [0]* (?:\s|$)/x

Input:  33.e19
**input  '33.e19'  is not valid
```